# What pixel size do images need to at least fill the iPhone 6 Plus display?

Tags: ios, iphone, screen-resolution

The iPhone 6 Plus has 414 x 736 points. It renders at 3x to get 1242 x 2208 pixels, which are mapped to 1080 x 1920 of physical pixel.

Since the physical pixels are the pixels which are actually drawn and shown to the user, I guess that full screen images have to be at least 1080 x 1920 px to match the full screen potential. Each image which is bigger than that will be downscaled to 1080 x 1920 px.

Am I right that you need at least have full screen images in size 1080 x 1920 px to get the best resolution on an iPhone 6 Plus?

Comment: This website might be helpful: http://www.iosres.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse with 'mapped to physical size'. You just use 1242 x 2208 px size for you full screen images.

The screen bounds of iPhone6+ is;

```
NSLog("Screen Size \( UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)"); // on iPhone 6+ - 414 x 736 (1x)
```

Which we are using in our development calculations so,
in development, there is no concept of physical screen size. it is handled by the device at its own.